# Update column's values if rows contain some words

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some doubts on how to mark as True/False rows that contains some words.

I have a list of words

```
my_list=['cat','dog','mouse']
```

and 4 columns in a dataframe:

```
Col1             Col2                  Col3             Col4
...  This is the story of a cat My dad is going to UK   False
...  My dog's name is Bert     The sky is so blue today False
... There is no one that understands me Why are you so sad? False
```

The first column does not matter so far. 
Column 4 was initially set based on some initial condition. However, I would like to change its value (False/True) in case of Col2 and/or Col3 contains one of the words in the list I mentioned above.

The expected output would be

```
Col1             Col2                  Col3             Col4
...  This is the story of a cat My dad is going to UK   True
...  The sky is so blue today   My dog's name is Bert   True
... There is no one that understands me Why are you so sad? False
```

as the first two rows contains at least one word from the list (cat and dog). 
I've tried using `sr.contains()`:

```
pattern = '|'.join(my_list)
df['Col2','Col3'].str.contains(pattern)
```

but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `apply` here

```
pattern = '|'.join(my_list)
df[['Col2','Col3']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains(pattern)).any(1)
```

Or

```
(df['Col2']+df['Col3']).str.contains(pattern)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @YOBEN_S. I was trying with the second one but I was doing it in a wrong way.